# Change the Content of a div from the navigation of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

SO gurus!

I just want to say that I'm REALLY REALLY new to JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX, and all of this, so I may not be understanding the answers I've already searched. If this is the case, what I'm really looking for is someone to dumb it down to complete idiot level, because I'm simply just not getting it.

H'okay. What I'm **attempting** to do is to prevent my site visitors from having to reload the page every time when they click a link in my navigation bar. I want the  links in my navigation `div` to replace the content in my main `<div>`, and I want  my "home page" to lead to an XML file where I have my "updates" (sort of like a blog, without being a blog).

Here's my page code:

```
<div class="nav"> 
    <h1>navigation</h1>
        <ul>
        <!-- I want these links' content...-->
            <li><a href="#">Home Page(this one is to be an XML)</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>

<div class="main">
<!--... to show here! -->
     <p>Bloop! New stuff here.</p>
</div>
```

Can someone please, please explain this to me in ENGLISH? I've been crying for an hour because I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand this correctly, what you want to do... change the content of the div (with the class name of "main", whenever the user clicks on a link?

If I were to do this in pure javascript (no framework)... I would do the following:

Assign the list items in the navigation an ID as followed:

```
<ul>
    <!-- I want these links' content...-->
        <li id="home-nav"> <a href="#">Home Page(this one is to be an XML)</a></li>
        <li id="test1-nav"> <a href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
        <li id="test2-nav"> <a href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>
        <li id="contact-nav"> <a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Next, you can go ahead an strip out the anchor tags, and you are going to want to add an onclick function to the nav items.

```
<ul>
    <!-- I want these links' content...-->
        <li id="home-nav"
            onclick="navigate('home-nav')"> 
             Home Page(this one is to be an XML)</li>
    </ul>
```

Notice how I added an ID of 'home-nav' and I added the onclick function of navigate, passing in 'home-nav' as a parameter. Next, you'll need to write the function in javascript.

```
function navigate(link){
  //Set the link to active
  document.getElementById(link).classList += "active";

 //Change data in the main div
 var main = document.getElementsById('main');
 main.innerHTML = "<p>Whatever you want the HTML to be.</p>
}
```

Finally, instead of using a "main" class... make it an id... the above code will present a few glitches that you will need to solve for, however it will get you started. Hope it helps.

Also, if you need to learn the Javascript basics, I recently did a code series that teaches JS Basics, here it is:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-4zzaVqc2ajx1dwggBv04D1ns9JBrosv

Comment: Ahhh, thank you so much! This... I understand...for the most part! Now, I have another question... in the .innerHTML, can I link to an XML file? or is that a different animal altogether?

Oh, and thank you for the YT link, I'm watching it now!

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **.remove()** and **.append()**. Look:

```
<ul>        
        <li><a id="link1" href="#">Test Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="link2" href="#">Test Link 2</a></li>            
    </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#link1").click(function(){
    $(".main").children().remove();
    $(".main").append("<p>Link 1 Stuff !</p>");
})
$("#link2").click(function(){
    $(".main").children().remove();
    $(".main").append("<p>Link 2 Stuff !</p>");
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm going to try this and get back.